# React table doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm able to access the values via console log, but it's not actually rendering anything or showing an error

```
    const columns = [
        {
          id: 1, // Assign a unique ID for this column
          Header: 'ID',
          accessor: 'id', // This should match the key in your JSON data
        },
        {
          id: 2, // Assign a unique ID for this column
          Header: 'First Name',
          accessor: 'first_name', // This should match the key in your JSON data
        },
        {
          id: 3, // Assign a unique ID for this column
          Header: 'Last Name',
          accessor: 'last_name', // This should match the key in your JSON data
        },
        {
          id: 4, // Assign a unique ID for this column
          Header: 'Email',
          accessor: 'email', // This should match the key in your JSON data
        },
        {
          id: 5, // Assign a unique ID for this column
          Header: 'Gender',
          accessor: 'gender', // This should match the key in your JSON data
        },
        {
          id: 6, // Assign a unique ID for this column
          Header: 'Date of Birth',
          accessor: 'dob', // This should match the key in your JSON data
        },
      ];
      
      
    const table = useReactTable({
        data,
        columns,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    })
```

Nothing fancy here

```
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup=>(
                                <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                                    {headerGroup.headers.map(header =>(
                                        <th key={header.id}>
                                            {flexRender(
                                                header.column.columnDef.header,
                                                header.getContext())}
                                        </th>
                                    ) )}
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
                            <tr key={row.id}>
                            {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                                <td key={cell.id}>
                                {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                                </td>
                            ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

This is the table part.

before I was using another mock data that I got from an api and I Was able to render only the columns, then I changed to this and not even the columns. there are no errors.

I'm even able to access the data [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD6XS.png)

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

I tried logging each step from table to table.getHeaderGroup()[0] blah until columnDef, and I'm able to get the date, same for rows. But the data is not rendering on teh screen

Okay I see the columns weren't rendering because of a typo but the cells still don't render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `accessor` with `accessorKey` and it will work fine.

Also, there is a typo. Replace `Header` with `header` to actually show the header.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    id: 1, // Assign a unique ID for this column
    header: 'ID',
    accessorKey: 'id', // This should match the key in your JSON data
  },
  {
    id: 2, // Assign a unique ID for this column
    header: 'First Name',
    accessorKey: 'first_name', // This should match the key in your JSON data
  },
  {
    id: 3, // Assign a unique ID for this column
    header: 'Last Name',
    accessorKey: 'last_name', // This should match the key in your JSON data
  },
  {
    id: 4, // Assign a unique ID for this column
    header: 'Email',
    accessorKey: 'email', // This should match the key in your JSON data
  },
  {
    id: 5, // Assign a unique ID for this column
    header: 'Gender',
    accessorKey: 'gender', // This should match the key in your JSON data
  },
  {
    id: 6, // Assign a unique ID for this column
    header: 'Date of Birth',
    accessorKey: 'dob', // This should match the key in your JSON data
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks!! I swear to got I spent 2 days with this :(